# Low flying helicopters at night (2300)

Tags: faa-regulations

I am just outside of Waynesboro Virginia United States and earlier I heard a helicopter approaching from the north but it was not visible at that moment. As the helicopter came into sight over the treeline I was able to see that it was flying rather low (approximately 50 meters) and that there were two helicopters. The lead helicopter was followed by a second helicopter at approximately 20 meters to it's 5 o'clock position. At first the only visible lights on the aircrafts was a red strobe located on the tail near the rear rotor. Earlier this same day I had observed what appeared to be a Hind (identified by the distinctive canopies at the front of the helicopter) as well as what appeared to be a Blackhawk (identified by the turbines and side door which was open at the time) flying similar headings but at different times. I mention this in case the unknown helicopters flying without lights were the same aircrafts or possibly of a similar type. My question is shouldn't they have had navigational lights on is there something I'm not aware of?